# NTP: synchronisation of time between two machines for ICMP timestamping

Tags: algorithm-analysis, reference-request, optimization, computer-networks, synchronization

Some guy on the internet [recommends](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/5133/296) using the same ntp server when it is required to troubleshoot asymmetric routes through ICMP, and it's somewhat important to have synchronised time between the two machines doing ICMP.

Granularity of timestamps in ICMP is 1ms (unique per 24h period), assume packet roundtrip between the source and destination of at least 100ms, each way of at least 50ms, plus jitter.

I find the recommendation of using the same ntp server unreasonable; for one, because it would seem that the likelihood of any given reliable ntp server, anywhere in the world, carrying correct time is much higher than the likelihood of transmitting said time through the internet over longer distances (plus with potential jitter and packet loss), e.g. a good collection of local servers is already the best you could do for the task at stake.

Basically, my conjecture is that, should a single ntp server be shared, it won't necessarily be a good server for both hosts doing ICMP, and would not contribute to the clock between the two (and only two) machines being the most synchronised, compared to a good collection of local servers instead.

What's the mathematical take on this?